# Oracle: Name is already used by an existing object although there is no object with that name

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle. I am trying to run a sql script from HPDMA which invokes all the table creation scripts required for my database and I get the following error:

> CREATE TABLE ABC.RESULTS_MODEL_OUTPUT
>   * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

I queried the database to see if there are any objects with the same name. I ran the following query:

> select * from all_objects where OBJECT_NAME like '%RESULTS_MODEL_OUTPUT%';

no rows are returned which means there is no object with the name 'ABC.RESULTS_MODEL_OUTPUT'. Then why is Oracle throwing me an error?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is the name all uppercase? all lowercase? quoted? Try using `upper(OBJECT_NAME) like ...` in the query.

Comment: always drop a table before creating it. so before your create add drop table schema.tablename

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Tried using the 'upper(OBJECT_NAME)' but that doesn't work either.

Comment: When you query `all_objects`, are you connected as user ABC? If not you just might not be able to see it. Check *as that user*, and/or in `dba_objects`. Also, check the script - maybe the table creation is being executed twice, from a stray slash perhaps. (Though that would perhaps imply it's cleaning up after itself, if you still can't see it afterwards...)

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, It worked for me. Initially, I was connected as a different user. Now, I see that it is present in all_objects. Thank you!

Comment: If the database says an object with that name exists, then an object with that name exists. Use DBA_OBJECTS if you have access to it. ALL_OBJECTS doesn't give you all objects in the database - it only lists those the logged-in user has access to. Also - are there indexes or constraints or other objects being created in-line with the creation of the table? if so the error may reference one of those. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged in as a different user and due to that I was not able to find the table name in all_objects table (As pointed out by @Alexpoole).

I am able to see it once I logged in as the user 'ABC'.