# how could i fix "create" error in oracle sql developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When I start to compile script, this error appears. I am newbie in Oracle SQL, so - could you help me?

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES
(
    ID number(10) NOT NULL,
    SALARY number(10) NOT NULL,
    ADRESS varchar2(60),
    SEX varchar2(60),
    PHONE_NUMBER varchar2(10),
    EMAIL varchar2(40),
    EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar2(12 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    SURNAME varchar2(20 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    FATHER_NAME varchar2(20 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    ID_DUTY number (15) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CLIENTS
(
    ID number(10) NOT NULL,
    CLIENT_NAME varchar2(12) NOT NULL,
    SURNAME number(20) NOT NULL,
    FATHER_NAME number(20) NOT NULL,
    PHONE_NUMBER char(10) ,
    ADRESS varchar(60)
);
```

Error screenshots:

[image]
  [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle: Name is already used by an existing object although there is no object with that name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911872/oracle-name-is-already-used-by-an-existing-object-although-there-is-no-object-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read how Oracle responded? It said

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

What does it mean? Usually, it means that table whose name is `employees` already exists and you can't create another object using the same name - `employees`. What to do? You have two options:

- drop existing object
- rename new object

However, that doesn't have to be a **table** that already exists - might be any other object, but uses the same name. For example, you might have had a view named `employees`, or a procedure, a trigger, ... any object. In order to find out what it is, query `user_objects`.

---

This is what you have now - you can't create a table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE employees(
  2    id             NUMBER(10)NOT NULL,
  3    salary         NUMBER(10)NOT NULL,
  4    adress         VARCHAR2(60),
  5    sex            VARCHAR2(60),
  6    phone_number   VARCHAR2(10),
  7    email          VARCHAR2(40),
  8    employee_name  VARCHAR2(12 CHAR)NOT NULL,
  9    surname        VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)NOT NULL,
 10    father_name    VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)NOT NULL,
 11    id_duty        NUMBER(15)NOT NULL
 12  );
CREATE TABLE employees(
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Which object - whose name is employees - do I already have?

```
SQL> select object_type from user_objects where object_name = 'EMPLOYEES';

OBJECT_TYPE
-------------------
TABLE
```

Aha, a table. How does it look like?

```
SQL> desc employees
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
```

Only one column? That's something *stupid*, probably I forgot to drop it. Does it contain any rows?

```
SQL> select * from employees;

no rows selected
```

No, it is empty. OK, so let's drop it and create my brand new `employees` table:

```
SQL> drop table employees;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE employees(
  2    id             NUMBER(10)NOT NULL,
  3    salary         NUMBER(10)NOT NULL,
  4    adress         VARCHAR2(60),
  5    sex            VARCHAR2(60),
  6    phone_number   VARCHAR2(10),
  7    email          VARCHAR2(40),
  8    employee_name  VARCHAR2(12 CHAR)NOT NULL,
  9    surname        VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)NOT NULL,
 10    father_name    VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)NOT NULL,
 11    id_duty        NUMBER(15)NOT NULL
 12  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Much better.

Comment: thank you a lot, if i had a more reputation, i woild like this answer